# How to remove duplicates from data frame using python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

```
dframe= pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A']*3 + ['B']*4 + ['C','B','A'],'col2':[2,3,4,2,4,2,1,3,4,4]})
```

I want to remove duplicates from both columns and final result should look like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A'] + ['B'] + ['C'],'col2':[2,4,3]})
```

I tried following but the result was not as per the expectations

```
dframe.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1'], keep='first')
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: "result was not as per the expectations" please describe what was exactly wrong with your output, or better yet show an example.

Comment: Welcome to the SO, however, I would like to see what is the expected output required of  the dataframe you have shown.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
We also expect you to do appropriate research and incorporate that into your post.  De-duplication is covered in many places on line, including handling common problems.

Comment: Thanks friends for trying, actually I was looking for final result with no duplicates so I provided the sample output as: 
pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A'] + ['B'] + ['C'],'col2':[2,4,3]})

However, one of the friends got the solution right:
out=dframe.agg(lambda x:pd.Series(pd.unique(x))).dropna()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

via `agg()` and `dropna()` method:

```
out=dframe.agg(lambda x:pd.Series(pd.unique(x))).dropna()
```

**OR**

via `apply()` and `dropna()` method:

```
out=dframe.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(pd.unique(x))).dropna()
```

output of `out`:

```
    col1    col2
0   A       2
1   B       3
2   C       4
```

Comment: Thank you so much Anurag Dabas, it worked. I tried to upvote but it seems since I am new here so I don't have 'reputation' to upvote. Will do as soon as I have that pal.

Comment: @ApurvYadav btw If it worked then if you wish you can try considering accepting this answer(click on tickmark to make it green)...Thnx **:)**